# Build application in landscape mode on Myphone TW1 Duo using LWUIT

Tags: java-me, midp

I want to run my application in landscape mode on MyPhone TW1 Duo using the LWUIT.

In Nokia devices I add the following attribute in JAD :

```
Nokia-MIDlet-App-Orientation - Landscape
Samsung devices : MIDlet-ScreenMode :Landscape
```

But when I add both this attribute on MyPhone TW1 Duo it will not play application on landscape it will play in portrait.

How to restrict LWUIT application on MyPhone TW1 Duo to landscape only?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general code to build app only in landscape mode. Only, the famous mobile providers like Nokia and Samsung gave JAD property to restrict the app in only landscape or portrait mode.

If you used **MIDlet-ScreenMode :Landscape** in JAD, you can't able to install the app in Nokia C5 because custom jad property can't start with name **Midlet-**.

[How to lock the landscape mode in j2me app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098607/how-to-lock-the-landscape-mode-in-j2me-app).

If you are using Canvas, try this.

[Create Landscape Game Canvas for Asha 303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923801/create-landscape-game-canvas-for-asha-303/10929977#10929977)